# error: too many initializers for 'tU8 [0] {aka unsigned char [0]}'

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have an issue with initializing an array which is part of an array of structures.
The type of the struct is

```
typedef stuct {
   unsigned char myarray[]; 
   bool flag;
}myStructType;
```

i have created an array of this struct type and want to initialize it

```
myStructType myStruct[2] = {
   {
      {5,6,7},
      false
   },
   {
      {1,2},
      true
   }
};
```

myStruct is a configuration structure and i have code which will loop through all the elements of the structure doing some actions based on the init values.

I am using arm-v5te-linux-gnueabi-g++ compiler in Linux embedded platform.

The problem is that when i compile the code, i get the following error

> error: too many initializers for 'unsigned char [0]'

Any solutions?
Thanks

Comment: What compiler and platform? Such a member is nonstandard.

Comment: You don't need the `typedef struct { } name` trick in C++, you can just do `struct name { }`. You should pick one language or the other.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, and want a dynamically sized array, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: the purpose of the structure is to hold configuration. I will add more events to the structure as and when there is a need. The design is to be used in a embedded solution.

Comment: @user2234576 Curious as to why you unaccepted the answer; if more information is available that makes the answer invalid, it would help other readers to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a compiler that would allow you to have such a `struct`. It would appear to be impossible for it to figure out how to access `flag`.

If you can, refactor `myarray` into another, linked, structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring compiler issues, consider this:

```
struct myStructType {
   unsigned char myarray[]; 
   bool flag;
};

myStructType a = { { 5, 6, 7 }, true };
myStructType b = { { 1, 2 }, true };
```

What is `sizeof(myStructType)` (or more importantly, what is the offset of `flag`)? That is unanswerable because this situation is not possible. You have a few options. You could hard-code a maximum size for `myarray`:

```
struct myStructType {
   unsigned char myarray[4]; 
   bool flag;
};
```

You could make it a pointer and initialize the arrays separately:

```
struct myStructType {
   unsigned char *myarray; 
   bool flag;
};

unsigned char a[] = { 5, 6, 7 };
unsigned char b[] = { 1, 2 };
myStructType myStruct[2] = { { a, true }, { b, false } };
```

You could do the same as above but use null-terminated strings instead:

```
struct myStructType {
   unsigned char *myarray; 
   bool flag;
};

unsigned char a[] = "\005\006\007";
unsigned char b[] = "\001\002";
myStructType myStruct[2] = { { a, true }, { b, false } };
```

Or directly, if `const` is ok on `myarray`:

```
struct myStructType {
   const unsigned char *myarray; 
   bool flag;
};

myStructType myStruct[2] = { 
    { "\005\006\007", true }, 
    { "\001\002", false } 
};
```

There are other options too.

By the way, you don't need the `typedef struct { } name` syntax in C++, you can just do `struct name { }`.

Comment: In fact, indeterminate sized arrays are allowed as members in C. They simply do not contribute to `sizeof`. The trick is illegal in C++ but many compilers allow it anyway. Having a member declared after such an array would never be allowed, though.